# Attempted to register RCTBridgeModule class RCTWebSocketModule

Tags: react-native, websocket, rctbridge

Attempted to register RCTBridgeModule class RCTWebSocketModule for the name 'WebSocketModule', but the name was already registered by class RCTWebSocketModule.

This error occurs when I run the iOS app using the command react-native run-ios.

[image: screenshot]